# JMX error running jhipster sample app

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

Error while running jhipster sample app :

```
[ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: null
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:411) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter$JmxListener.onGaugeAdded(JmxReporter.java:494) ~[metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry.notifyListenerOfAddedMetric(MetricRegistry.java:344) ~[metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry.onMetricAdded(MetricRegistry.java:338) ~[metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry.register(MetricRegistry.java:89) ~[metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.writer.CodahaleMetricWriter.set(CodahaleMetricWriter.java:107) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.writer.CompositeMetricWriter.set(CompositeMetricWriter.java:54) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.writer.DefaultGaugeService.submit(DefaultGaugeService.java:41) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [na:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository: cannot add mbean for pattern name metrics:name=gauge.response.
```

Comment: How do you run the application? "mvn spring-boot:run" ?

Comment: Yes. And also, I ran this in the IntelliJ IDE and same error.I am on a windows machine

Answer (score 2):

I come late, but I ran into the [same issue with RESTX](https://github.com/restx/restx/issues/126), and after further investigation this happens when the URL contains character interpreted as pattern in JMX MBean names (i.e. `*` and `?`). Indeed when the framework (in your case spring boot) adds a metric for this URL, the JMXReporter from Codahale Metrics in turns tries to register an MBean with that name, which fails with that exception (the message is not very helpful).

The [source code for the JMX Repository](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/com/sun/jmx/mbeanserver/Repository.java/#410) better show the problem.

Possible solutions:

- upgrade Metrics to v3.1.0 or greater (name changed from codahale metrics to dropwizard metrics), and register your own [ObjectNameFactory](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/master/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/DefaultObjectNameFactory.java) fixing this problem. This is [the approach I've used in RESTX](https://github.com/restx/restx/commit/a23cd7375404714721268f5c8935795e567d1cb8).
- disable the JMXReporter at least for this URL if you can (I haven't checked spring boot to see if you can)
- override the metrics filter to escape the characters causing the problem